# Cannot start emulated Android device/AVD device in Windows 7

Tags: windows, android-emulator

I follow the official Android guide [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html#Emulator) but I cannot start the emulated device. It keeps saying `PANIC Cannot start device...` as below screenshot.

Do you have the same problem and any work around for me?

**Creating the device**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Starting the device**

[image]

[image]

**PANIC/failed result**

[image]

Comment: In what OS are you developing? Windows?

Comment: Did you change the RAM from 1024 to 768 as indicated? I used to get this error message, and after I started to make this change for any AVD in my Windows 7 I never seen the message anymore.

Comment: @FranciscoAlvarado Nope I didn't change that. We have the solution as below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these steps

1. Create a environment variable called: `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` and set it to `C:\Users\<<Administrator>>`
2. Open `Eclipse > Window > Preferences`, click in `Run/Debug` and `String Substitution`. Add a new variable called `user.home` and set it to `C:\Users\<<Administrator>>`
3. Create an AVD and run it.

**Note** The `<<Administrator>>` means the name of your Windows account; it is where resides the folder which contains your `.android` directory

An android project member says [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19084):

> As a work-around, you can define the environment variable
>   ANDROID_SDK_HOME to point to the directory containing your .android
>   directory. The emulator and SDK Manager will pick it up properly.
>
> Also you should check that the AVD is created in the location
>   D:\NN\.android\avd (check in your screenshoots, just above the list
>   of AVD, the path in List of existin Android Virtual Devices).

Comment: My PC doesn't exist the path `C:\Users\Administrator` in step 1. Does that mean any user who has administrator access right?

Answer (score 1):

Uncheck scale display to real size, It will work for you,
Or try to lower the Screen size column.

Comment: Tried it and that not works

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, which nearly drove me crazy. System: Win7 64Bit, Eclipse/ADK 64 Bit, JRE7 64 Bit - latter copied from `C:Programs\Java\` as "jre" under the Eclipse folder... (finally Eclipse started). 
How I solved the lacking start of the Emulator with an android virtual device:

1. Look under `C:Users\YourUserName\ .android` if you can find there a folder named
   \avd containing subfolders named after the android virtual devices you created.
   If that is not the case (as it was on my machine) then you probably have moved long ago your account's user data via a symbolic link to some different location, as it was the case in my system. Eclipse (the virtual device manager of the ADK) will create the virtual devices there, but will search for them in the Windows default `C:Users\YourUserName\ .android` path.
2. Locate the real folder with your user data, in my case it was:

   ```
   D:\Win\Users\YourUserName
   ```

where I finally found the AVD-folders needed for Eclipse:
`D:\Win\Users\YourUserName\ .android\avd\.`..(2 Subfolders with the avd's)

3. Just copy the avd-folder (in my Example)

   ```
   D:\Win\Users\YourUserName\ .android\avd
   ```

to the "usual" Location, where Eclipse looks for it, to

```
C:\Users\YourUserName\ .android
```

This enabled me to : Start the virtual device and to load the Hello World example from Eclipse into it.

What did not help:

Create an environment variable named
`ANDROID_SDK_HOME` with the value  `D:\Win\YourUserName\ .android`
and add it to the environment variable paths list:

```
path= ....;%ANDROID_SDK_HOME%;....
```

Eclipse does not seem to search for such environment variables, but obviously rather relies on the presence of all of the files in the Windows default locations of the user's personal data.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things that you can do to get it over with.

1. Copy the content of `/root/.android/avd` to `$HOME/.android/avd.` Just a matter of a simple command and worked for me. :D
2. Before Android searches for `.ini` files in `$HOME/.android/avd`, it looks for an environmental variable `$ANDROID_AVD_HOME`.

   So you can set its value to `/root/.android/avd.` :)